# In and at uses in city and places or any alternative?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

What is right?

- I live in Seattle?
- I live at Seattle?

and can I use Hails instead and how?

Comment: yes but i am more concerned towards whether we can use Hails instead and how?

Answer (score 3):

Definitely 'live IN Seattle'.

As for the street, it depends. Certainly if you were giving a specific address, with the house number, I would say 'AT 45 Anywhere Street'.

For saying the road/street name only, I would use either 'on' or 'in'. I think it depends on the context and the physical shape of the road concerned. If the road is reasonably wide or long, I would more likely say 'on'. If the road is small or curvy or within a smaller enclave of similar roads, I would more likely say 'in'.

It's a tricky one! (And if relevant, I'm British.)

Answer (score 0):

- You live IN a city AT number 123 ON xxx street unless you are British in which case it seems you may live IN xxx street.
- [Hail from](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hail) is originally nautical. 
  From where do you hail? - From what shore did you call?
  To hail from somewhere is very archaic. I would use it in [jest](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=jest)

> > My good sir, I hail from the grand city of Chapman's haven.

Comment: In the UK, you live ***in*** a street - see [ON an American street, but IN a British one](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/54251/43980)

Comment: Same link you gave tells us that if you live in Cavendish, it's because it was an area like Kensington. I have lived in London and I am sure British people would live IN Kensington but ON Kensington High Street

Comment: I strongly disagree. See the answers from ColinFine & FumbleFingers and the comments below them (and my own answer). As discussed there, we live *in* an area, "*at* an address", or "*in* a particular street/road". If someone lives "*on* Kensington High Street", they are likely to be homeless. As also discussed there, we might say "*on* a particular road/street" when referring to a large building, etc., but we do **not** live "*on* a street".

Comment: If you live IN the street, you've better watch out for the cars ;)

Comment: As you may have seen from my answer there, I actually live in *"The Street"*. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, so you live on the only street where you have to say IN the street so as to not come across as homeless ;)))

Comment: In the US, if you are "in the street" you are actually on the pavement; children are told not to play in the street.  If you (literally) live "in the streets" you are homeless.  Strangely perhaps, you would walk on the road, but one might find you lying in the road.

Comment: @BobRodes "*On* the street" is homeless in the UK, and, according to tchrist, that is also the expression in the US (see his comment to my answer linked above). Yes, children also played "*in* the street" here (before it became too dangerous!).

Comment: On the street is one of the expressions in the US; in the streets is another and probably less specific one.  For example, if a young person spends his time "in the streets" it implies that he's getting up to no good instead of making something of his life.